# Segmentation fault on returning from main (very short and simple code, no arrays or pointers)

Tags: c++

I've been wondering why the following *trivial* code produces a segmentation fault when returning from main():

```
//Produces "Error while dumping state (probably corrupted stack); Segmentation fault"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
    vector<int> numbers;
};

int main()
{
    Test a;
    ifstream infile;

    cout << "Last statement..." << endl; // this gets executed
    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly,
1) if only one of the two variables is declared, I don't get the error,
2) if I declare a vector variable instead of an object with a vector member, everything's fine,
3) if I declare an ofstream instead of an ifstream, again, everything works fine.
Something appears to be wrong with this specific combination...

Could this be a compiler bug? I use gcc version 3.4.4 with cygwin.

Thanks for the tips in advance.

Gábor

Comment: gcc 3.4.4 is ancient. Can you try with the 4 series?

Comment: I recall seeing a bug report with something similar, I can't remember exactly though so I can't find it. But I'm pretty confident this is an obscure bug that has since been fixed.

Comment: Come come. I remember when 3.0 was state of the art. Now gcc 2.95/2.96 now there was an old and wacky compiler.

Comment: I just tried to compile your program in g++ version

    g++ (GCC) 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)

and it works fine

Comment: Funny it should work for you, Thanh, with the same version of gcc. (Although I don't really see why the gdc and dmd version is relevant here; aren't these related to the D programming language?)

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug.  If this is your entire program, there is absolutely nothing wrong with it.  You have discovered a bug in the compiler or standard library.  As was recommended to you in the comment, try a 4.x series gcc compiler.  The 3.x series is old as the hills.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt answers/comments. Unfortunately, upgrading the compiler is no simple matter in this case. I'm developing a psychology experiment with a C library called Tscope, which is dependent on the Allegro game library. Tscope comes prepackaged with a cygwin environment, gcc compiler, basic IDE, etc. The problem is: Allegro does not compile on the more recent cygwin anymore. And I don't believe just replacing gcc.exe would work, would it?

Comment: @Gábor Kovács - No, that wouldn't be enough.  But I believe cygwin has a packaging system that allows you to selectively upgrade.  So you could try that.